# How to set a custom gwei / gas price on uniswap/sdk Javascript using ethers.js module?

Tags: contract-deployment, gas, javascript, uniswap, ethers.js

Im building an app to do trades on uniswap using ethers module. ive created contracts and imported the router and the factory contracts using this code:

```
const factory = new ethers.Contract(
  addresses.factory,
  ['event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint)'],
  account
);
const router = new ethers.Contract(
  addresses.router,
  [
    'function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
    'function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts)'
  ],
  account
);
```

And now i pull a trade using swapExactETHForTokens function:

```
        const tx = await router.swapExactETHForTokens(
            amountOutMin // Slippage is set here too, if not wanted change to => amounts[1]
            [tokenIn, tokenOut],
            addresses.recipient,
            Date.now() + 1000 * 60  //1 minute expiry time for contract.
        );
```

My question is how do i implement custom gwei in my trade , there dont appeart to be an argument within uniswap trade functions for gwei at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an optional final parameter to any smart contract function call, which is an object, which can contain keys like `value` (for attaching ETH to the transaction, which is definitely what you will need to do when calling `swapExactETHForTokens`), and also `gasPrice` (for setting the gas price, in gwei).

```
const tx = await router.swapExactETHForTokens(
  amountOutMin,
  [await router.WETH(), tokenOut], // swapping WETH for a token
  addresses.recipient,
  Date.now() + 1000 * 60,
  { 
    value: "1000000000000000000", // 1 eth
    gasPrice: "100000000000" // 100 gwei
  }
);
```